# How to find first match in multiple files

Tags: command-line, find, grep

Is there a way for the find command to search for the first match or occurrence of a string or pattern **within each** of multiple files? I've been using the usual syntax:

```
 find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec command 'pattern' {} \;
```

(I also happen to be searching pdfs with `-exec pdfgrep` but suppose that would be a special case of the general problem and may be dealt with afterwards or separately.)

Keep in mind this is not same as the commonly-asked problem of producing the first result from a search using find with `-quit` or `head -n 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `-m` option of GNU `grep` which stops reading the file after (in the example) one match.

```
find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec grep -m 1  'pattern' {} \;
```

Comment: I'd like to search the first match for each of the files rather than quit after the first file.

Comment: This command should do just that. It will continue searching each file regardless of any match of any file that find examines.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with an awk script:

```
find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec awk '/pattern/{print;exit}' {} \;
```

Comment: I've tried -quit with -exec (pdf)grep but that only exits after the first result; I'd like to search multiple files for first matches.

Comment: Why are you using `-quit`? That tells `find` to exit after the first match.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of grep and sed, much less for awk (which I hadn't considered.) Your solution does indeed work (now just to append the filenames that contain the matches, sort of pdfgrep style.)

Answer (score 2):

If the searching command has no way to stop after the first match, you can filter its results and keep only the first output line: `command 'pattern' /path/to/file | head -n 1`. The command will receive a SIGPIPE signal when `head` exits, so it might go on looking for a few more matches due to buffering but it will stop before the end of the file if there are a lot of matches.

Since you need to run a shell command (to set up the pipe), you need to invoke `sh` from `find`. Mind the quoting: you need one layer of quotes for the outer shell, and another for the shell started by `find`. You can put single quotes around the inner shell command and work in single quotes with the `'\''` hack (end single quote literal, `\'` for a literal single quote, and start a new single quote literal in the same breath), this way you don't need any different quoting in the pattern (unless the pattern contains a `'` that you represented as `'\''`, in which case you'll need to make that `'\'\\\'\''`).

```
find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec sh -c 'command '\''pattern'\'' "$0" | head -n 1' {} \;
```

Instead of worrying about quoting the pattern, you can put it outside and pass it as a parameter.

```
find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec sh -c 'command "$0" "$1" | head -n 1' 'pattern' {} \;
```

It will be slightly faster to invoke only one shell and loop over the files.

```
find dir -iname '*.ext' -exec sh -c '
    for f; do command "$0" "$f" | head -n 1; done
' 'pattern' {} +
```